# Inspect on hover eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hover, settings

Is there a way I can make it so **Inspect** (see picture from context menu) is called when I **hover** on a selected text/code in an editor (e.g. Java editor)? I can see the menu at **Preferences->Java->Editor->Hovers** but I was wondering if I could tweak it more than that as I need to be able to debug things like `this.getInstance()`

[image: Right click on some code shows Inspect and a keyboard combination Ctrl+Shift+I]

I'm running Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

The Hover options in Eclipse are those that you see :

[image]

There is not any option for the execution of statements and it makes sense for a Hover option.
If the statement to execute with `inspect` doesn't have any side effect, your idea would be acceptable.
But if the statement has a side effect, it would be undesirable to have random executions according to the pointer of the mouse on the screen.

Note that other debugger tools are less strict than  Eclipse : instead of using the hover + key combination, they use the selection of the expression to evaluate and display its result.
But Eclipse doesn't have this option.
A workaround in Eclipse would be to change the `Inspect` shortcut (in Key preferences) with a much simpler shortcut such as the `i` letter.
In this way select `this.getInstance()` + `I` entered trigger the inspection :

[image]